# Search and replace inside an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, associative-array, replace

I need to search and replace inside an associative array.

ex:

```
$user = "user1"; // I've updated this

$myarray = array("user1" => "search1", "user2" => "search2", "user3" => "search1" ) ;
```

I want to replace `search1` for `search4`. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE: I forgot to mention that the array has several `search1` values and I just want to change the value where the `key is == $user`. Sorry for not mention this earlier.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$myarray = array("user1" => "search1", "user2" => "search2" );

foreach($myarray as $key => $val)
{
    if ($val == 'search1') $myarray[$key] = 'search4';
}
```

Comment: A pretty straight forward and simple solution

Comment: @Alfacinha: If an answer has solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check-mark to it's left, so that other's coming to this post will know that it's the right solution.

Comment: Pro: it's basic code every PHP developer is familiar with. Con: it's slower than the function meant for this operation, `array_map()`. Con: the initial array is edited in-place, which can be sometimes handy but is usually a bad practice, especially since it makes it hard to define unit test on this code.

Answer (score 2):

There's a function for this : [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
// Using a lamba function, PHP 5.3 required
$newarray = array_map(
    function($v) { if ($v == 'search1') $v = 'search4'; return $v; },
    $myarray
);
```

If you don't want to use a lambda function, define a normal function or method and callback to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$user = "user1";
$myarray = array("user1" => "search1", "user2" => "search2", "user3" => "search1" );
foreach($myarray as $key => $val)
{
    if ($val == 'search1' and $key == $user )
    {
       $myarray[$key] = 'search4';
       break;
    }
}
print_r($myarray);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [user1] => search4
    [user2] => search2
    [user3] => search1
)
```

Comment: Make sure you add `break;` inside the `if` to stop iterating after the key has been found. No point iterating over the entire array if the value has already been set.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do

```
if (isset($myarray[$user])) $myarray[$user] = 'search4';
```

Comment: yup, we tend to complicate things !

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalArray = array( "user1" => "search1" , "user2" => "search2" );
$pattern = 'search1';
$replace = 'search4';

$replacedArray = preg_replace( '/'.$pattern.'/' , $replace , $originalArray );
```

Fixes the risk mentioned in comment in response to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142627/search-and-replace-inside-an-associative-array/7142659#7142659)

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

Since the post was updated, and I have had chance to get some sleep, I realized my answer was stupid. If you have a given key and you need to change it's value, why iterate over the whole array?

```
$user    = 'user1';
$search  = 'search1';
$replace = 'search4';
$array   = array('user1' => 'search1', 'user2' => 'search2');

if (isset($array[$user]) && $search === $array[$user]) $array[$user] = $replace;
```

---

Similar to @Joseph's method (pretty much the same), but with a few tweaks:

```
$user = 'user1';
$array = array("user1" => "search1", "user2" => "search2" );

foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
    if ($key === $user) {
        $value = 'search4';
        break; // Stop iterating after key has been found
    }
}
```

Passing by reference is a nicer way to edit inside `foreach`, and is arguably quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Search and replace inside an associative array or numeric
Replace value in any associative array and array can be any deep

```
function array_value_replace($maybe_array, $replace_from, $replace_to) {

    if (!empty($maybe_array)) {
        if (is_array($maybe_array)) {
            foreach ($maybe_array as $key => $value) {
                $maybe_array[$key] = array_value_replace($value, $replace_from, $replace_to);
            }
        } else {
            if(is_string($maybe_array)){
                $maybe_array = str_replace($replace_from, $replace_to, $maybe_array);
            }               
        }
    }

    return $maybe_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want for particular key then you just add condition for key in previous ans like.

```
$user = "user1";
$myarray = array("user1" => "search1", "user2" => "search2" );

foreach($myarray as $key => $val)
{
    if ($val == 'search1' && $key == $user) $myarray[$key] = 'search4';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Using str_replace should work:

```
$myarray = array("user1" => "search1", "user2" => "search2" ) ;

$newArray = str_replace('search1', 'search4', $myarray);
```

Comment: This is dangerous code. If the array contained the value "search12", it would be changed to "search42".

Comment: I actually thought that was the desired outcome - search and replace vs. value replacement. Perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -1):

Following on from Joseph's answer, using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) may enable you to use the code in other situations:

```
function pregReplaceInArray($pattern,$replacement,$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $array[$key] = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$value);
    }   
    return $array;
}
```