# Replace empty string in double quotes in php

Tags: php, arrays, replace, double-quotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search and replace inside an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142627/search-and-replace-inside-an-associative-array)

I think this may have been asked before. But I just want a simple solution.

I have an array like this:

```
  Array (   "name" => "Krish",
            "age" => "27",
            "COD" => ""
        )
```

I want to replace ""  with "0"

Its a multidimentional array. The return value should be array too.

Edit: I tried preg_replace and str_replace. For some reason, these did not work for me.

Comment: Start writing code. If you can't get it to work, come back and ask again. If you are just looking for a hint to get started, you need to loop through the array(s) and replace any values of `""` with `0`.

Comment: @Kevin Rave preg_replace and str_replace are used for strings whereas you are using an array. you should either convert it to string. or loop the array and manipulate it according to your requirement. consider my example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    "name" => "Krish",
    "age" => "27",
    "COD" => ""
);
```

you may loop the array and repalce what you want

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if($value == "") $array[$key] = 0;
}
```

Note:

if you know what key is it you can do it like this

```
$array['cod'] = 0;
```

Comment: Do we need a loop? Thought there should be a one line code for this.

Comment: This only changes the local value of `$value`. You should use a reference instead `&$value`

Comment: yeah, you need a loop if you want to determine if the value is empty. if you know what key is it that you want to replace then you can do it in one line of code.

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert & jeroen thanks for pointing it out. fixed it

Answer (score 1):

```
$entry = array("name" => "Krish",
               "age" => "27",
               "COD" => "");
$arr = array_filter($entry, 'valcheck');
print_r($entry); //ORIGINAL ARRAY
print_r($arr); //MODIFIED ARRAY
function valcheck($var)
{
    if($var === "")
        return 0;
    else
        return $var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your array is `$array`:

```
$array['COD'] = "0";
```

Comment: Its a multi dimensional array. Want it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr=array(
    "name" => "Krish",
    "age" => "27",
    "COD" => ""
);

print_r(array_map(function($i){return (''===$i)?0:$i;},$arr));
?>
```